# Displaying the average next to the array

Tags: java, arrays, string, return, average

I'm new to Java, so apologies.

I've got two arrays:

```
int[] grades = {64,55,45,67,65,88};
String[] unitCode = {"APP:","BSAD:","CF","DAD:","N&CS:","POP:"};
```

And I need to bring each one next to each other to form:

```
[APP:64, BSAD:55, CF45, DAD:67, N&CS:65, POP:88]
```

I've managed to achieve this with this code:

```
    public String[] unitMarks(int[] grades, String[] unitCode) 
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (double i : grades)
        sum += i;
        double average = (sum/grades.length);

            for (int i = 0; i <grades.length; i++)
            {
                String combination = unitCode[i]+grades[i];
                unitCode[i] = combination;

        }

            return unitCode;
    }
```

But I also need to display the average grade at the end of it, so it should say:

```
[APP:64, BSAD:55, CF:45, DAD:67, N&CS:65, POP:88, Average:64.0]
```

I've already written the code for finding the average of the grades array. I'm just having trouble with returning the average with the combined array (and also displaying "Average:" before it).

I've tried doing things like -

```
String includedAverage = unitCode+" Average:"+average;
return includedAverage;
```

But then it starts saying that it can't convert from String to String[].
If i change the method return type to String it doesn't work with this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArrays.unitMarks(grades, unitCode)));
```

Any help or pointers would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a result array which has one more space than your `unitcode` array and assign the values to it instead of modifing the input:

```
public String[] unitMarks(int[] grades, String[] unitCode) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (double i : grades) {
        sum += i;
    }
    double average = (sum / grades.length);
    String[] result = new String[grades.length +1];
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        String combination = unitCode[i] + grades[i];
        result[i] = combination;
    }
    result[result.length-1]= "Average:"+average;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing this.
1. Use ArrayList which grows in size when you add elements to it

```
public List<String> unitMarks(int[] grades, String[] unitCode) 
{
    List<String> unitCodeArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    double sum = 0;
    for (double i : grades)
    sum += i;
    double average = (sum/grades.length);

        for (int i = 0; i <grades.length; i++)
        {
            String combination = unitCode[i]+grades[i];
            unitCodeArrayList.add(combination);

         }
        unitCodeArrayList.add("Average:"+average);
        return unitCodeArrayList;
}
```

2. Use primitive array but append to it this way (as I am not sure what is the size of it)

   ```
   public String[] unitMarks(int[] grades, String[] unitCode) 
   {
   double sum = 0;
   for (double i : grades)
   sum += i;
   double average = (sum/grades.length);
   for (int i = 0; i <grades.length; i++)
   {
           String combination = unitCode[i]+grades[i];
           unitCode[i] = combination;
   }
       String[] resUnitCode = appendArray(unitCode, "Average:"+average);
       return resUnitCode;
   }
   private String[] appendArray(String[] array, String x){
   String[] result = new String[array.length + 1];
   for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
       result[i] = array[i];
   result[result.length - 1] = x;
   return result;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to display the values, you could use Stream to compute average and display in one go:

```
private void displayGradesAndAverage(int[] grades, String[] unitCode) {
    IntStream.range(0, grades.length)
            .peek(i -> System.out.print(unitCode[i] + grades[i] + ", "))
            .map(i -> grades[i])
            .average()
            .ifPresent(avg -> System.out.println("Average:" + avg));
}
```